# How to forbid Json.Net to convert ints to bools for deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

```
public class RootobjectTest
{
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public Rates rates { get; set; }
}

public class Rates
{
    public float AED { get; set; }
    public float AFN { get; set; }
    public float ALL { get; set; }
    public float AMD { get; set; }
    public float YER { get; set; }
    public float ZAR { get; set; }
    public float ZMK { get; set; }
    public float ZMW { get; set; }
    public float ZWL { get; set; }
}

var jsonData = @"{ ""timestamp"": 1370340068,  ""base"": ""USD"",  ""rates"": {       
""AED"":
3.672958,    ""AFN"": 54.154801,    ""ALL"": 107.66425,    ""AMD"": 419.62875,  
""YER"": 214.964253,    ""ZAR"": 9.813218,    ""ZMK"": 5227.108333,    ""ZMW"": 5.344453,
""ZWL"": 322.387247  }}";

var currencyRates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootobjectTest>(jsonData);
```

All is good and works perfectly. But if I change

```
public int timestamp { get; set; }
```

to

```
public bool timestamp { get; set; }
```

I don't get any errors. Json.Net parses int value of timestamp and converts it to bool. Is there elegant and simple way to forbid this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  I'm not sure I understand why you would need/want to change `timestamp` from `int` to `bool` in the first place such that you would then need a way to prevent the deserializer from trying to honor it.

Comment: I'm just curious about this type conversion. And If I don't know exact types of json fields I can get interesting results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making Json.Net strict would require quite a bit of work, but it can probably be done (you'll have to implement custom strict `JsonConverter`s for all types you need). Official position of the library's author is to use JSON schemas for validation.

I wouldn't worry about validation too much though, unless it actually becomes an issue. There're a lot of dynamically typed languages out there which convert variable types any way they want, and people somehow manage to use them effeciently. :) Json.Net folows the same philosophy.